# SqlServerCompact EFCore Model Generation

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I want to generate a EF Model in a C# WindowsForm project (under .NET6 ) from a SQLServerCompact file.

Using Scaffold-DbContext command (see below) I receive an error:

> Method ‘Create’ in type
> ‘EFCore.SqlCe.Scaffolding.Internal.SqlCeDatabaseModelFactory’ from
> assembly ‘EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact40, Version=2.2.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9af395b34ac99006’ does not have an
> implementation.

this is the command executed

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection “Data Source= C:\temp\TestModelEFCore\TestModelEFCore\dbsqlcompact\gsdata.sdf;” -Provider EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact40 -OutputDir dbsqlcompact/Entities -ContextDir DatabaseModel -Context MyContext -UseDatabaseNames -f -Verbose
```

[image]

Any suggestion?
I saw this is a deprecated package: EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact40.

thank you

Comment: Entity contains a mapping between the c# classes and the database tables/fields.  You need to update the mapping to resolve the error.  Migration Update will fix the issues.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?force_isolation=true&tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: but I'm not migrating, I'm creating a new model from an existing  database.

Comment: Migration has two modes : Create and Update.  Latest does not allow "From Database", only From c# classes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix major versions, if you really MUST use that deprecated provider, your must use EF Core 2.2 everywhere.

Comment: Which is the alternative insteed deprecated version? I was a little bit confused. is there a documentation elsewhere? I didn't find it.

Comment: I have published an EF 6 Classic provider, that is the only current alternative (or stay on EF Core 2.2)

Comment: If I go here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact40 there is written that is deprecated! I mainly work with .net framework and I want to move my project in .net6 as SqlServerCompact EF model. What I have to do? is there a guide? thks

Comment: You can use this https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErikEJ.EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact/6.4.0-beta3